# (Unity) Is there a way to disable collision detection on BoxColliders but still detect it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I have 4 BoxColliders on my character to detect wall/floor collision.

When collision detection is enabled for them, it causes the player to stick to walls and slopes aren't detected as ground.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the box collider a trigger, but using box colliders for detecting ground ( floor ) isn't the best idea, you could try using a simple checksphere to check if the player is grounded or not. First make an empty game object, make sure it's a child of your character, and put it at its bottom. Then put this inside your character movement script, or just make a new script.

```
[SerializeField] private Transform GroundCheck;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask groundMask;
[SerializeField] private float groundDistance;

void Update()
{
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(GroundCheck.position,groundDistance,groundMask);
}
```